# add horizontal line histogram gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I would like to add a horizontal line in my histogram in gnuplot, is that possible?

My histogram has on the x axis: alea1 alea 2 alea3 nalea1 nalea 2 nalea 3
and the y axis goes from 0 to 25.

At 22, I want to add a horizontal line that goes all the way across from one end to the other end of the histogram.

Answer (score 17):

Try adding

```
, 22 title ""
```

at the end of your plot command. Works for my test data (file "histo"):

```
# Year  Red   Green  Blue
1990    33    45     18
1991    35    42     19
1992    34    44     14
1993    37    43     25
1994    47    15     30
1995    41    14     32
1996    42    20     35
1997    39    21     31

plot "histo" u 2 t "Red" w histograms, "" u 3 t "Green" w histograms, "" u 4 t "Blue" w histograms, 22 title ""
```

(taken from Philip K. Janert, Gnuplot in Action)

Comment: It took me a little while to figure out what you were saying here.  You might want to demonstrate an entire plot command just to show exactly what you mean.

Comment: done, @mgilson. I always find it a bit challenging without data in the original question.

Comment: `notitle` is somewhat cleaner than `title ""`

Comment: Well, the `22` works. But is it possible to have the line start at some point `x`?

Comment: @Philipp Ludwig - the other answer using arrows is probably the way to go if you need more options

Answer (score 13):

The typical way to add horizontal and/or vertical lines is with an `arrow`

```
set arrow from x1,y1 to x2,y2 nohead linestyle ...
```

For a horizontal line, y1 and y2 will be the same.  From your question, I'm a little unsure what you mean by "at 22", but I'm guessing you mean that you want to plot the line `y=22` on top of your histogram.  If that's the case, try this (before your `plot` command).

```
set arrow from graph 0,first 22 to graph 1,first 22 nohead lc rgb "#000000" front
```

Comment: Thanks both of you. I have done it with the arrow. Is it possible to add a line and words for me to say what the line at y=22 means in my histogram, like a legend?

Comment: @AudreyLee-Gosselin -- sure.  just do `set label "some text" at ...,...`.  however, you could also do that with the other answer:  `plot <histogram_stuff>, 22 w lines title "some text"` to actually put it in the plot key.