# gnuplot strange behavior when not using "first" option

Tags: plot, gnuplot, gnu

I was having trouble plotting a horizontal line

```
...
set arrow 2 from graph 0, y(x) to x, y(x) nohead
...
```

For clarity, assume that `x = 1 => y = 3` So as far as I understood, that should have generated a line from `(0,3)` to `(1, 3)`. However, the `y` coordinate of the first point `(0,3)` turned out to appear somewhere outside the plot. But if I use (according to [a post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497160/add-horizontal-line-histogram-gnuplot#13498286))

```
set arrow 2 from graph 0, first y(x) to x, y(x) nohead
```

then it yields the output I wanted.

Can someone explain to me the magic above using `first`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth reading `help coordinates` to learn about the different coordinate systems. In short, the `first` coordinate system is that defined by the current ranges of the x and y axes: the bottom left corner of the graph has coordinates (xmin,ymin), and the top right corner has coordinates (xmax, ymax). In the `graph` coordinate system the bottom left corner is always (0,0) and the top right corner is always (1,1), independent of the ranges of the two axes.

Here is a brief example:

```
set xrange [-4:4]
set yrange [-3:3]
set grid
set arrow 1 from first 0,0 to first 1,1 ls 1 lw 3
set arrow 2 from graph 0,0 to graph 1,1 ls 2 lw 3
plot 1/0 ti ""
```

[image]

The purple vector is arrow 1, which goes from (0,0) to (1,1) in the `first` coordinate system. The second vector is arrow 2, which goes from (0,0) to (1,1) in the `graph` coordinate system.

The default rules for which coordinate system will be used are

> If the coordinate system for x is not specified, `first` is used.  If
>   the  system for y is not specified, the one used for x is adopted.

and for the special case of `set arrow`,

> A coordinate system specifier does not carry over from the first endpoint description [to] the second.

It sounds like you want to use the `first` coordinate system, so you shouldn't have to do anything:

```
set arrow from 0, y(x) to x, y(x)
```

When you use

```
set arrow from graph 0, y(x) to x, y(x)
```

you use the `graph` coordinate system for the starting point, and the `first` coordinate system for the end point.

When you use

```
set arrow from graph 0, first y(x) to x, y(x)
```

you use the `graph` coordinate system for the starting point's x coordinate, and the `first` coordinate system for the remaining coordinates. If range of the x axis starts at zero, this would be the same as using the `first` coordinate system for everything.

Comment: I call this a complete answer and I'll definitely keep it my mind.