# Scale the values/labels on an axis

Tags: gnuplot, octave

Ive a data set with the below range of values,

```
x from 0 to 100

y from 0.0 to 10.0^10
```

I'm using `plot` function to draw the graph `plot(x, y)`. The graph is drawn but with the below warning of converting the `y` values from integer to float.

```
multiplot> set ytics in scale  1.4 border mirror ( "0" 0,  "1e+10" 10000000000,  "2e+10" 20000000000,  "3e+10" 30000000000,  "4e+10" 40000000000,  "5e+10" 50000000000,  "6e+10" 60000000000,  "7e+10" 70000000000) textcolor rgb "#262626" font ",10";
line 2: warning: integer overflow; changing to floating point
```

The `y` values are already in float, but not sure why this warning is thrown. Is it possible to set explicit formatting([Format specifiers](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html)) on the `axis` or `ytics` ?

A similar question is posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774650/how-to-draw-a-horizontal-line-at-the-large-y-axis-integer). But seems like those are `gnuplot` commands/options. How to use the same options in octave `plot` ?

**Edited**

**Code**

```
> 
> 
> x = round(rand(10)(1,:) .* 100)
x =

   76   13   11   79   72   78   36    8   21   63

> y = rand(10)(1,:) .* 1e+10
y =

   5836992276.93708   6471394539.45494   7847697654.87665   2495557143.74836   2694348406.60242   9736785473.26907    756349861.48275   9948115214.16169   4768610059.59765   6621668613.33630

> plot(x,y)

multiplot> set ytics in scale  1.4 border mirror ( "0" 0,  "2e+09" 2000000000,  "4e+09" 4000000000,  "6e+09" 6000000000,  "8e+09" 8000000000,  "1e+10" 10000000000) textcolor rgb "#262626" font ",10";
                                                                                        ^
           line 0: warning: integer overflow; changing to floating point

multiplot> set ytics in scale  1.4 border mirror ( "0" 0,  "2e+09" 2000000000,  "4e+09" 4000000000,  "6e+09" 6000000000,  "8e+09" 8000000000,  "1e+10" 10000000000) textcolor rgb "#262626" font ",10";
                                                                                                             ^
           line 0: warning: integer overflow; changing to floating point

multiplot> set ytics in scale  1.4 border mirror ( "0" 0,  "2e+09" 2000000000,  "4e+09" 4000000000,  "6e+09" 6000000000,  "8e+09" 8000000000,  "1e+10" 10000000000) textcolor rgb "#262626" font ",10";
                                                                                                                                  ^
           line 0: warning: integer overflow; changing to floating point

multiplot> set ytics in scale  1.4 border mirror ( "0" 0,  "2e+09" 2000000000,  "4e+09" 4000000000,  "6e+09" 6000000000,  "8e+09" 8000000000,  "1e+10" 10000000000) textcolor rgb "#262626" font ",10";
                                                                                                                                                       ^
           line 0: warning: integer overflow; changing to floating point

multiplot> set ytics in scale  1.4 border mirror ( "0" 0,  "2e+09" 2000000000,  "4e+09" 4000000000,  "6e+09" 6000000000,  "8e+09" 8000000000,  "1e+10" 10000000000) textcolor rgb "#262626" font ",10";
                                                                                        ^
           line 0: warning: integer overflow; changing to floating point

multiplot> set ytics in scale  1.4 border mirror ( "0" 0,  "2e+09" 2000000000,  "4e+09" 4000000000,  "6e+09" 6000000000,  "8e+09" 8000000000,  "1e+10" 10000000000) textcolor rgb "#262626" font ",10";
                                                                                                             ^
           line 0: warning: integer overflow; changing to floating point

multiplot> set ytics in scale  1.4 border mirror ( "0" 0,  "2e+09" 2000000000,  "4e+09" 4000000000,  "6e+09" 6000000000,  "8e+09" 8000000000,  "1e+10" 10000000000) textcolor rgb "#262626" font ",10";
                                                                                                                                  ^
           line 0: warning: integer overflow; changing to floating point

multiplot> set ytics in scale  1.4 border mirror ( "0" 0,  "2e+09" 2000000000,  "4e+09" 4000000000,  "6e+09" 6000000000,  "8e+09" 8000000000,  "1e+10" 10000000000) textcolor rgb "#262626" font ",10";
                                                                                                                                                       ^
           line 0: warning: integer overflow; changing to floating point
> 
> 
>
```

**Output**

[image: Resulting Graph]

Comment: Please add a MCVE

Comment: @Andy, I've updated the post with the sample code and the resulting graph. Hope it helps.

Comment: @NEB did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @Snekse Nope, I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this maybe what you are looking for? Although, having `1e10` written as `10000000000` is not very "user-friendly".

```
set xrange[0:100]
set yrange[0:1e10]

set format y "%.0f"

plot exp(x)
```

[image]

Comment: The settings you are using are from the [Format Specifiers](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node184.html) of gnuplot. My struggle is to use those settings in the `octave` code. I'm not sure how - still in the learning phase. The octave equivallent of `set xrange[0:100]` in the above code (that I'm aware of) is `axis([0, 100]); xbounds = xlim(); set(gca, 'xtick', xbounds(1):20:xbounds(2));` Can you please port the above code piece to `octave` syntax, if you are aware of it ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know `octave`. I hoped that `gnuplot` would also be ok for you. Maybe somebody else can comment.